# Bash: weird echo behavior

Tags: bash, csv, echo

I'm trying to make a parser for a program's automatically generated log and the part of the parser that generates a csv started having a strange behavior.
The part that's going crazy is this one:

```
echo "$COMMAND_3_NAME,,$TIME_1_START,$TIME_1_END,$DIFF_1,,$TIME_2_START,$TIME_2_END,$DIFF_2,,$TIME_3_START,$TIME_3_END,$DIFF_3,,$TIME_USR_START,$TIME_USR_END,$DIFF_USR" >> $OUT_NAME
```

This line is generating the following output:

```
Command_3,,458.7
484.0,483.9
507.5,-458.7
967.9
507.5,,271.8
271.8,271.8
271.8,-271.8
543.6
271.8,,,,,,967.8
967.8,967.8
967.8,-967.8
1935.6
967.8
```

And there shouldn't be any \n in there because i do a "sed "s/\n//g"" in every single variable i'm printing.

Comment: Does your version of sed convert '\n' to a newline, or does it treat is as two literal characters '\' and 'n'?

Comment: better yet try `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: I don't see the ',' at the end of each line. you omitted them from your post or the echo ignores them ?

Comment: There weren't supposed to be any new lines. What i posted is the exact output of the program.

Answer (score 1):

For the input

```
foo
bar
```

sed runs the expressions on the strings `foo` and `bar`, not `foo\n` and `bar\n`.

`sed -e 's/\n//g'` therefore doesn't replace any line feeds.

To delete line feeds, you can pipe it through `tr -d '\n'` or use the bash variable expansion `"${myvariable//$'\n'/}"`

Comment: That's not the issue. The problem is echo is replacing ',' with '\n'. I added the sed line after the problem occurred.

Comment: It isn't replacing `,` with `\n`, since there are several `,`s with no line feeds around them. More likely, the variables themselves contain line feeds. `printf "%q\n" "$TIME_1_START"` will probably show `$'458.7\n484.0'`. To remove them, see answer.

Comment: So where are the ,s going? Read the echo line again and count the ,s.

Comment: There are 16 commas in both.